# Extending React Types for CSS custom attributes

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm converting my React project to TypeScript, but can't figure out how to extend React.HTMLPorps to accept custom CSS data-attributes.

A common pattern that I use in my project is:

```
const MyComponent = ( ) => <div mycustomattr="true"/>;
```

I've tried creating an interface like so:

```
interface ExtendedDiv extends HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {
    mycutomattr: "true" | "false";
};
```

However, I'm not sure how to apply this to JSX div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 ways:

1. easiest way is to rename atribut - `custom` => `data-custom`. But this will results in:

```
<div data-custom="true" />
```

2. extend react interface `HTMLAttributes` but it will allow this attribute to all elements

```
interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
  // extends React's HTMLAttributes
  custom?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know adding a dash to the naming convention simply solves the errors. Thank you!